# how do you use windowPosition in nightwatch.js?

Tags: nightwatch.js

How do I use the windowPosition function in nightwatch.js?

http://nightwatchjs.org/api/windowPosition.html

I want to get the current position of the window browser.

Answer (score 0):

This took me a moment to figure out as well!

```
client.windowPosition('current', (res) => {
  console.log(res.value.x, res.value.y);
});
```